# XML parser in BeautifulSoup only scrapes the first symbol out of two

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I wish to read symbols from some XML content stored in a text file. When I use `xml` as a parser, I get the first symbol only. However, I got the two symbols when I use the `xml` parser. Here is the xml content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lookupdata symbolstring="WDS">
    <key>
        <symbol>WDS</symbol>
        <exchange>NYE</exchange>
        <openfigi>BBG001S5WCY6</openfigi>
        <qmidentifier>USI79Z473117AAG</qmidentifier>
    </key>
    <equityinfo>
        <longname>
        Woodside Energy Group Limited American Depositary Shares each representing one
        </longname>
        <shortname>Woodside Energy </shortname>
        2
        <instrumenttype>equity</instrumenttype>
        <sectype>DR</sectype>
        <isocfi>EDSXFR</isocfi>
        <issuetype>AD</issuetype>
        <proprietaryquoteeligible>false</proprietaryquoteeligible>
    </equityinfo>
</lookupdata>
<lookupdata symbolstring="PAM">
    <key>
        <symbol>PAM</symbol>
        <exchange>NYE</exchange>
        <openfigi>BBG001T5K0S1</openfigi>
        <qmidentifier>USI68Z3Z75887AS</qmidentifier>
    </key>
    <equityinfo>
        <longname>Pampa Energia S.A.</longname>
        <shortname>PAM</shortname>
        <instrumenttype>equity</instrumenttype>
        <sectype>DR</sectype>
        <isocfi>EDSXFR</isocfi>
        <issuetype>AD</issuetype>
    </equityinfo>
</lookupdata>
```

When I read the xml content from a text file and parse the symbols, I get only the first symbol.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("input_xml.txt") as infile:
    item = infile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(item,"xml")
for item in soup.select("lookupdata symbol"):
    print(item.text)
```

current output:

```
WDS
```

If I replace `xml` with `lxml` in `BeautifulSoup(item,"xml")`, I get both symbols. When I use `lxml`, a warning pops up, though.

As the content is xml, I would like to stick to `xml` parser instead of `lxml`.

Expected output:

```
WDS
PAM
```

Comment: "As the content is xml" - The content is not XML since there is no root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the builtin `xml` library only loads the first item, it just stops after the first `lookupdata` ends. Given all the examples in the [xml docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) have some top-level container element, I'm assuming it just stops parsing after the first top-level element ends (though am not sure, just an assumption). You can add a `print(soup)` after you load it in to see what its using.

You could use `BeautifulSoup(item, "html.parser")` which uses the builtin `html` library, which works.

Or, to keep using the `xml` library, surround it with some top-level dummy element, like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("input_xml.txt") as infile:
    item = infile.read()

patched = f"<root>{item}</root>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(patched, "xml")
for found in soup.select("lookupdata symbol"):
    print(found.text)
```

Output:

```
WDS
PAM
```